# Разделение текста: не разбивать текст дальше первого пробела

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

Есть такой код:

```
t, x = text.split()
```

Я ввожу допустим 2 аргумента

```
.тест я люблю печеньки
```

Как сделать что бы последний аргумент`я люблю печеньки` с пробелами не считался за отдельный аргумент?(
Но в то же время мне нужно что аргументов было 2

Я знаю что можно просто поменять символ сплита на запятую или еще что то. Но мне нужен именно пробел.

Comment: Можете как-то выделить текст, котоый вводите? А то не очень ясно, где он начинается, где кончается (например, `.тест я люблю печеньки`)

Comment: @Anton поправил, надеюсь понятнее

Comment: `t, x = text.split(maxsplit=1)`

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
t, _, x = '.тест я люблю печеньки'.partition(' ')
```